# UISwitch set to ON and it doesn't show the Modal View Controller transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I created a custom UISwitch for my iPhone app with NSUserDefaults and added a modal view controller (PincodeSetupViewController) for Pincode to setup. Here is the info the user will see:

1. When the user clicks to launch the app first time on the mainViewController shows UISwitch is already set to OFF because the user doesn't setup the Pincode. That is correct.
2. Next step is when the user decides to turn the switch to ON and it must display the modal view controller (PincodeSetupViewController) immediately. It slides from bottom to top. That is correct.
3. Now the user closed the app and opens it again. It shows the switch set to ON already because the user did this to setup Pincode. That is correct.
4. The user decided to turn the switch OFF and back to ON. When the switch is set to ON again, it displays the modal view controller (PincodeSetupViewController) immediately. **The problem I have here is that the modal view controller doesn't transition slide from bottom to top, it just appears abruptly. This is not correct.** I want that modal view controller to transition slide from bottom to top instead of abruptly.

Does anybody know what is wrong with it? Any suggestion appreciated.

mainViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    customSwitch = [[RCSwitchOnOff alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 0.0, 74, 40)];  
    [customSwitchView addSubview:customSwitch];
    [customSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(togglePincode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pincode"]) {
         NSLog(@"SWITCH MESSAGE: ON");
         [customSwitch setOn:YES];

    } else {
         NSLog(@"SWITCH MESSAGE: OFF");
         [customSwitch setOn:NO];
    }
}
```

---

```
- (void)togglePincode:(UISwitch *)sender {

    if(sender.on){
         NSLog(@"Switch is ON");

         NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"pincode"];
         [userDefaults synchronize];

         //Check to see if the user already setup the Pincode or not.
         if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"setupdone_status"]) {
               NSLog(@"Display Pincode Setup");

               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"setupdone_status"];

               UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
               UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PincodeSetupViewController"];
               [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

               [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; 

         } else {
               NSLog(@"No Pincode Setup");
         }

    } else {
         NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
         NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"pincode"];
         [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"setupdone_status"];
         [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

---

AppDelegate.m I added some code in applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate methods

```
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pincode"]) {
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"setupdone_status"]; 

    } else {
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"setupdone_status"];
    }
```

Comment: @DustinRowland The user clicked on home button to close the app and then clicked the app to reopen it.

Comment: @DustinRowland Yes, I did. I added in PincodeSetupViewController.m [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I see that you're using storyboard. What you should do is create a modal segue from your main controller to your other controller, and do `performSegueWithIdentifier`. I think the problem is you instantiating a view controller each time. If you use a segue and then dismiss the controller, everything should work (I've never had a problem with this method).

Comment: @DustinRowland I tried the performSegueWithIdentifier and it has the same problem as above, no transition slide just appears abruptly after I reopened the app. :-(

Comment: Did you remove your instantiation and storyboard methods?

Comment: @DustinRowland You may see that screencast I provided, so you can see what is wrong with it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx69cegr2enzj6z/Screeny.mov

Comment: So it looks like the problem only occurs when you leave the switch at on and then reopen the app. I'll make a sample project and see if I can duplicate the error.

Comment: Still trying to dupe your error... just so you know  `viewDidAppear` is not called when the app is reopened after a home button press.

Comment: @DustinRowland I created NSNotificationCenter in mainViewController.m so the viewDidAppear is called when the app is reopened after a home button press.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your setup as best as I could and didn't get an error. Here is the code I used:

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)switchChange:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *valueOfSwitchON;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *theSwitch;

@end

//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize valueOfSwitchON;
@synthesize theSwitch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    valueOfSwitchON = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([valueOfSwitchON boolValue] == YES) [theSwitch setOn:YES];
    else [theSwitch setOn:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTheSwitch:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)switchChange:(id)sender 
{
    if ([self.valueOfSwitchON boolValue] == NO)
    {      
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalSegue" sender:self];
        valueOfSwitchON = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        valueOfSwitchON = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
}
@end

//  ViewController2.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
- (IBAction)closething:(id)sender;

@end

//  ViewController2.m

#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)closething:(id)sender 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Storyboard:
[image]

I hope this helps (note that I just set up a lot of things purely in IB that you were creating programmatically)

Comment: I tested it and it was ok but it doesn't have NSUserdefaults for switch. I added some of my code into the small sample which I posted. You may see it here (.xcode file): http://cl.ly/1G2f2X1k011P3C0r133k

Comment: You should be able to add `NSUserdefaults` to it easily. Does it work overall? I just meant it to be a way for you to see what part of your code was causing the error.

Comment: So you have a resurgence of your previous error or `NSUserDefaults` gives you a new error?

Comment: Before you added NSUserDefaults it worked, after you did it didn't? Your sample project works for me.

Comment: Yes, before I added NSUserDefaults and it worked but after I added NSUserDefaults and it didn't work. (I deleted my previous comment which was a wrong comment. sorry!)

Comment: I have been playing around with the code, and I really have no idea what is wrong. What you should do is, now that you have a more specific issue, post another question about it. That way it's easier for someone who might know the answer to find it and help you.

Comment: Yes, I have no clue what is wrong with it. I posted the same question to Apple iOS Dev Center Forum. I will let you know if I resolve it. Thank you so much for your help.